# Accessing S3 directly from EMR map/reduce task

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am trying to figure out how to write directly from a EMR map task to the s3 bucket. I would like to run a python streaming job which would get some data from the internet and save it to s3 - without returning it back to reduce job. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just set the output of your MR job to be a s3 directory and tell it that there is no reducer:

```
./elastic-mapreduce ..... --output s3n://bucket/outputfiles --reducer NONE
```

That should do what you want it to.

Then your script can do something like this (sorry, ruby):

```
STDIN.each do |url|
  puts extract_data(url)
end
```